# How to use div class style elements in node.style?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to incorporate css styles associated with particular div class names using node.style. I can get the styles to work individually but I am trying to implement multiple styles that span within one another using the div classes mentioned. I am wondering if there is a way of doing this using an easier method or can it be done at all?

```
var node = document.createElement("wall-post");  
var image = new Image();
image.src = obj.picture;
node.appendChild(image);
node.style=' display: inline-block;margin: 15px;margin-top: 30px; border-radius: px;overflow-y: hidden;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);float:left;';
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `node.className = "yourclass"` and use css to define the styling of that class

```
.yourclass {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 15px;
   margin-top: 30px; 
   border-radius: px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `style` **property** on an element isn't a string, it's an *object* with properties for the styles. You set them individually.

```
node.style.display = 'inline-block';
node.style.margin = '15px';
node.style.marginTop = '30px';
node.style.borderRadius = /*?? Your question just has 'px' */;
node.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
node.style.boxShadow = '0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)';
node.style.float = 'left';
```

Note that you use the `camelCase` version (well, or `node.style["margin-top"] = "..."`).

Alternately, if you want to completely replace the style, you can do that by using `setAttribute` to replace the `style` entirely:

```
node.setAttribute('style', ' display: inline-block;margin: 15px;margin-top: 30px; border-radius: px;overflow-y: hidden;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);float:left;');
```

---

All of that aside: In general, supplying style information in JavaScript code isn't a great pattern to follow. Create a descriptive class, then use that class on the element.

Comment: Appreciate the solution as well as the general advice! Apologies for the misplaced node tag also!

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property is related to the `style` attribute which accepts, as its value, the **body** of a CSS rule-set. It associates those rules with the particular element.

Selectors, including class selectors, appear outside the rule-set's body and cannot be included in a style attribute. (It doesn't make sense to do so anyway, the style attribute is associated with a specific element, so there is no point is selecting a different one from that context).